# preg_match positive lookahead trouble

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have two strings

```
<span class="price" id="product-price-2095">$425.00</span>
<span class="price" id="product-price-355">$25.00</span>
```

I need to extract the prices $425.00 and $25.00 from these strings

Ive been using this

```
preg_match('/(?<=<span class="price" id="product-price-[0-9]{3}">)(.+?)(?=<\/span>)/s', $product, $priceArray);
```

The problem im having is with the [0-9]{3} part.  It will only work on the 25.00 price
but if i change the 3 to a 4 it will only work on the 425.00 price
Ive tried [0-9]{3,4} but i get the following error

Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length at offset 56

What can i do to make it match regardless of the number here "product-price-###"?

Comment: Can't you just match `$\d+(\.\d+)?`? Or better, use DOM and find `span[class="price"]`.

Comment: cant use it because the page has other prices on it that it matches first, the preg_match needs to have the ID part thats shown above

Comment: General war cry would be to not use regex against HTML. DOM with XPath here can do a great job. But if you insist on using regex, you can still try this: https://eval.in/41079

Comment: Im going to have to look into DOM and XPath, it seems with this project this keeps coming up over and over again.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lookarounds have their place, but unfortunately can't be variable. Here's a method without the look-arounds. I'm capturing with grouping so you can pick and choose from the array provided with `preg_match_all()`.

```
<?php

$string = '<span class="price" id="product-price-2095">$425.00</span>
<span class="price" id="product-price-355">$25.00</span>';

$pattern = '!(<span\sclass\="price"\sid\="product-price-\d{3,4}">)([^<]+)(</span>)!i';
$m = preg_match_all($pattern,$string,$matches);

print_r($matches)

?>
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <span class="price" id="product-price-2095">$425.00</span>
            [1] => <span class="price" id="product-price-355">$25.00</span>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => <span class="price" id="product-price-2095">
            [1] => <span class="price" id="product-price-355">
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => $425.00
            [1] => $25.00
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => </span>
            [1] => </span>
        )

)
```